# JPA: should I generate entities from tables, or generate tables from entities?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entities

In short, I am working on a new project relatively big one...many tables, many associations, inheretence.... ( so far I've created the UML & MCD)

I am wondering about what is the best way to proceed from this step: should I create the database manually and then generate entities using JPA, or should I create entities manually first and then generate my database ? what is the best way to do this so I can avoid bigger problems later...

Comment: liquibase script which generate DB, then generate entities from DB

Comment: I decided to go with generating db from entities, it makes more sens to me now since I'm not using any stored procedures or things like that... besides I'm not having the tables created yet for my application. refer to accepted  answer for more informations on why I decided to go with this approche. Thanks @ByeBye

Comment: I would not let JPA manage my database structure, because all of the standard options for it destroy your data. Whether to generate entities from tables or do it manually, that's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends :-).

- If your application "owns" the database (is the only user), it usually makes sense to treat the database as an implementation detail, and let JPA create it. That way, you don't have to mess with SQL, and the database always matches what JPA expects. This is useful also for scenarios like testing, as described by Essex Boy's answer.
- If the database already exists, or is meant to be shared with other applications, the your choice is already made - you have to use what is there (and change it with care).
- There may be external constraints on the database structure. Maybe you must use stored procedures, or use certain DB naming conventions, or you use a tool for schema migration during updates that imposes constraints. In that case you will need detailed control of the DB structure, which usually means you must create it yourself with SQL.

So, check the constraints that you are working under, then decide.

Comment: Thanks ! I've decided to go with generating db from entities based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you let the entities generate the tables.

This will also help with testing and development, for example you can use an H2 database which is built and torn down for each test.

I wouldn't even look at the database until a project is reasonably advanced.

The JPA entities can begin life without any table or column names, then as the project advances column and table names can be agreed without any impact on the rest of the code.

In a final integration stage minor changes can be made to entity JPA annotations to allow for specific datatype anomalies of Oracle, DB2 etc.

Applications should be responsible for their own databases.  This is especially relevant for a new project.

Comment: "Applications should be responsible for their own databases." While a viable point of view, this is something not everyone agrees on. For a long time, databases where considered a good way for multiple apps to interoperate. This is possibly changing now, e.g. microservices are supposed to have their "own" database, but it's by no means something everyone agrees on.

Comment: I am sure that plenty will disagree, this is my view.  The question implies there is no existing database.  Stored procedures are terrible on so many fronts (in my opinion),  Naming conventions can be accommodated with JPA annotations.  Liquibase rather than SQL should be used for changes.

Answer (score 1):

Schema generation (done by an ORM layer) is a convenience functionality but the resulting schema should be validated in every case by a human who is firm with databases (a DBA) before it goes to production. Even first creating the schema and then creating the proper ORM mapping is the more performant / reliable way.

Comment: True, I should give the db creation code (which I'll generate later on since I've decided to generate db from entites) to a DBA before the app goes into production... it usually goes this way in mid-big range firms

Answer (score 1):

Tables from entities or neither. Never create your object model from the data model. Always create your object model from a domain analysis. JPA is *not* a data-manipulation tool, it's an object-manipulation tool.

If you don't have control of the database schema, you'll just have to hope it supports the object model, and figure out how to map your object model to the relational model. That's why it's called object-to-relational mapping (ORM), not relational-to-object mapping.

Never but never let the data model drive your object model.

Comment: I've never thought about it this way ! this actually make sens, A LOT. 
I would've accept this answer if it made sens to every user(beginners too) to help future SO visitors.

Comment: "Never" is a strong statement... but I agree with the spirit: Don't let your thinking be railroaded by an existing database schema.

Comment: If you can think of a counterexample ...